# Customizing Axis points in R

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2

As you can see from the screenshot, the X-Axis points are all jumbled. Is there a way to make them appear vertically so that they can be read?

And is there a way to specify the interval in the Y-Axis?

I am using ggplot2's qplot.

```
qplot(merged[[1]], merged[[4]], colour = colour, xlab="Positions", ylab ="Salary", main="H1B Salary 2012", ylim=c(50000,300000))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without sample data and your actual code it is hard to give exact answer.

Generally, axis texts formatting is changed using function `theme()` and argument `axis.text.x=` (for x axis). To set breaks for y axis, `scale_y_continuous()` should be used with arguments `breaks=`.

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,vjust=0.5))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,5,0.5))
```

More information about theme() features is on [ggplot2 site](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/theme.html).

Comment: That worked! Is the theme used to change the spacing in between the axis points as well?

Comment: You can set size of axis texts or make axis longer to get wider space between each two points. Look at help page [theme](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/theme.html) to see examples.